# Update a field from other field with button

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I have a problem when I update field1 with the value of field2 from button in the same form.

```
<field name="field1" />

<field name="field2" />

<button name="button1" type="object" />
```

Here is method code:

```
def button1(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    ...

    return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'field1': field2}, context=context)

_columns = { 

    'field1': fields.integer('Field1'),

    'field2': fields.integer('Field2'),

}
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code for `button1` method, so that we can help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to browse that record and than assign it's value to a field1.

Try with this

```
def button1(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    field2 = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context).field2

    return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'field1': field2}, context=context)
```

Comment: field2 = self.browse(cr, uid, id, context=context).field2 because its one object no ?

Comment: *self.browse* give you a bunch of value as table contains number of columns.  *self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)* gives you a that and we take *field2* from it.